# How to set config show/hide refresh button on AppBar

Tags: react-admin

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGygA.png)

Button refresh on `AppBar` is not refresh on page Dashboard because I just use Component `Card` but work on page using component `List` or `Datagrid`, so I want to config show/hide refresh button on `AppBar` or how to fix it work for page not use component `List` or `Datagrid`.

Sorry I'm not strong in English.

Comment: I didn't understood your question. Can you please detail what you want to do, what did you try, and what are you expecting please ?

Comment: @Kmaschta I fix the detail on my question I hope you will understand.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand ... Can you answer to the following questions with small sentences: What are you trying to do ? What are you trying ? What are you expecting ? And what is the current behavior ?
Please, show us a maximum of code you are using.

Comment: @Kmaschta I test run project in `example/demo` on repo react-admin. When I push the refresh button on AppBar at page Dashboard page is not refresh but I push the refresh button on AppBar at page Customers page is refresh. I don't know why. So how to use refresh button in Dashboard page or config show/hide the refresh button

Comment: @Kmaschta Is possible to config hide/show the refresh button on the top right  of page and if it not how to make it work with the page that not use the data table list i.e Dashboard page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to fetch some data from the react-admin state for it to work. Indeed, the refresh button just trigger the `refreshView` action which update the `state.admin.ui.viewVersion` key of the the react-admin redux state. This key is a simple counter. Internally, we use this counter to check whether we must update some components data. Here is a simple example of a connected `Dashboard` which can do things when refreshed:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.doOnMountAndWhenRefreshed();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.views !== this.props.views) {
      this.doOnMountAndWhenRefreshed();
    }
  }

  doOnMountAndWhenRefreshed = () => {
    // This is where you do update your component:
    // - Make API requests
    // - Fetch data from the react-admin store, etc.
  };

  render() {
    const { views } = this.props;
    return <div>Refreshed {views} times.</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ views: state.admin.ui.viewVersion });

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(Dashboard);
```

You can see it working in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/w7q31pyq8k)

**Edit** for newer version of react-admin

```
import { useVersion } from 'react-admin';

const Dashboard = () => {
    const version = useVersion();
    return <div>Refreshed {version} times.</div>;
}
```

Comment: how can we implement the same using useEffect hook in functional based component

Comment: Use both useVersion to get the version and useRefresh to get the refresh function

Comment: useVersion no longer exists in react-admin@4. There is no substitute.

Answer (score 1):

In react-admin 4.x I managed to get the desired behaviour like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'

const noop = async () => new Date().valueOf()

export const MyDashboard = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery('myDashboard', noop)

  return (
    <div>Last refreshed at {data}</div>
  )
}

export default MyDashboard
```

Note how `data` represents the value returned by `noop()`.

That way, whenever the user presses the refresh icon in the AppBar, the component is re-rendered.

Comment: Should be noted that when browser is focus again it also rerender.